# How to avoid SerializationException warnings with Vstest.console.exe and Moq

Tags: exception, moq, mstest, vstest

I have a .NET 3.5 project with a corresponding unit test project.

First of all, since the Update to VS 2013 I cannot longer run the test project with MSTest. I learned that `vstest.console.exe` is the new preferred way to execute the tests.

Nevertheless, during the test run with `vstest.console.exe` which executes 550 UnitTests, all of them successful, my console gets spammed with a LOT of these exceptions:

```
Warning: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Moq, Version=4.2.1402.2112, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
```

I don't know what I did wrong.
I can only guess that because the tests are executed `in Isolation` mode (probably because of .NET Framework 3.5), it needs to transfer some objects between app domains, and here these exceptions occur.

My Question is:
Why can't the assembly be located? The Moq.dll is right beside my unit test assembly. What can I do to prevent these hundreds of exception messages during the test run?

**Update:**

I was being asked to run the fusion logger alongside, and it gave me this info:

```
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO    12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Moq, Version=4.2.1402.2112, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Moq.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Moq/Moq.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Moq.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Moq/Moq.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Moq.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Moq/Moq.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Moq.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Moq/Moq.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Now, I am asking why it does not use the Assemblies provided with my test project.
I cannot copy the `Moq.dll` to any of these paths, since I run multiple test projects in the same test run that use different versions of some assemblies and I could only provide one specific version here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue.

It seems that in the Moq NuGet package the Moq.dll in the lib\net35\ Folder is a dll built against .NET 4, and this cannot be loaded when the test is run in a .NET 3.5 environment.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar warnings on the build machine. The reason turned-out to be MockExceptions being thrown during the unit tests execution (All tests were successful even in my case, because of async-await weirdness).

Trick to identify these exceptions is to 'Debug' the unit tests instead of 'Running' (Right click and select Debug Selected Tests at project level). Fixing these MockExceptions got rid of the build warnings for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that this test project does not run with MSTest and not in VS anymore. The only way to execute the tests is with the `vstest.console.exe` and so I can't debug the tests as the test runner will immediately exit in VS without running a single test.

Comment: I had the same problem. Debugging the tests as suggested above showed there was an issue related to applying MockBehavior.Strict without setting up the Dispose method (of a disposable object of course). What troubles me is that in this case the test should have failed, but appeared to have succeeded. Thus it looks like these warnings should NOT be ignored.